# Inline-block почему то растягивается на всю ширину родителя

Tags: html, css, flexbox, inline-block

Есть такой html:

```
                <div class="properties__item item">
                    <div class="item__img">
                        <img src="/imgs/block_2/1.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item__title">Corporate catering</div>
                    <div class="item__text">We are able to serve events from 2 to 2000 guests and always
                        reasonable prices.</div>
                    <a class="item__btn btn btn--b">Get a quote</a>
                    <a class="item__link link link--b">View menus</a>
                </div>
```

И scss:

```
.btn {
    font-family: Bebas;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    padding: 12.5px 33px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn--w {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.btn--b {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 25%;
    flex-direction: column;
    @media (max-width: 770px) {
        flex: 0 1 50%;
    }
    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        flex: 0 1 100%;
    }
    &__img img{
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    &__btn {
        margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
        @media (max-width: 770px) {
            margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
        }
    }
}
@media (max-width: 920px) {
    .item__btn {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 770px) {
    .item__title {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 620px) {
    .item__btn {
        font-size: 9px;
        padding: 6px 16px;
    }
    
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .item__btn {
        font-size: 12px;
}
```

Проблема такая, этот "properties__item item" я делаю через flexbox, и кнопка btn, несмотря на то что она inline-block всё равно растягивается на весь флекс элемент, из-за этого приходится задавать кнопке ширину, но потом из-за этого страдает адаптив

В общем результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должен быть таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста. Объясните начинающему фронтедеру что не так  и почему так?

Comment: Ты привел обрывок кода, с которым нельзя понять в чем проблема, приведи полный код. Не понятно, что ты задавал родителю, какая структура и т.п.

Comment: Редактировал вопрос, теперь есть полный scss

Answer (score 0):

Лучше кнопку делать через `button`. Полезно для семантики и поисковых роботов.
btn можно попробовать прописать `width` в процентах (они будут считаться от родителя. Но только если родителю задана ширина)
А вообще не помешает посмотреть на css для всего блока, а не только для кнопки

Comment: К слову, возможно, родителю установлено свойство stretch, которое "растягивает" все дочерние элементы (то есть ту самую кнопку)

Comment: Исправил вопрос, теперь весь scss для блока

Comment: Я добавил ширину в процентах кнопке и она стала нормальной
Просто добавил
` .btn {
 width: 80%;
}`
У тебя может быть не 80%. Опять же, напомню, что проценты считаются от родителя. Т.е. в данном случае от .item

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, через `div` кнопки не делаются.
Если ваша кнопка ведёт на другую страницу, делайте её через `a`, а если должно открываться какое-то модальное окно, то через `button`
Советую изучить основы HTML/CSS

upd. Добавь отступы между самими карточками. Примерный код кинул ниже.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="properties">
        <div class="properties__item item">
            <div class="item__title">Corporate catering</div>
            <div class="item__text">We are able to serve events from 2 to 2000 guests and always
                reasonable prices.</div>
            <a class="item__btn btn btn--b">Get a quote</a>
            <a class="item__link link link--b">View menus</a>
        </div>
        <div class="properties__item item">
            <div class="item__title">Corporate catering</div>
            <div class="item__text">We are able to serve events from 2 to 2000 guests and always
                reasonable prices.</div>
            <a class="item__btn btn btn--b">Get a quote</a>
            <a class="item__link link link--b">View menus</a>
        </div>
        <div class="properties__item item">
            <div class="item__title">Corporate catering</div>
            <div class="item__text">We are able to serve events from 2 to 2000 guests and always
                reasonable prices.</div>
            <a class="item__btn btn btn--b">Get a quote</a>
            <a class="item__link link link--b">View menus</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.properties{
    display: flex;
    gap:30px;
}
.properties__item {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.item__btn {
    display: block;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}
```

[image: Скрин выполнения кода]

Comment: Исправил тег на а, но ничего не поменялось

Comment: Отредактировал сообщение.